# Showing that triangles have same area

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $abcd$ and $aefg$ be two squares in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ with one common vertex- without any oberlapping otherwise.

How can I show that the triangles $ade$ and $agb$ have the same area without knowing any angles?
I have no idea how to even start.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hint: both triangles have the same height (over their respective bases in $abcd$), which you can find as the sine of a certain angle in the diagram.

Comment: $AD\perp AD$, $AG\perp AE$ $\Rightarrow$ $\angle BAG = \angle DAE$ or $\angle BAG=180^\circ-\angle DAE$. Then $\sin BAG=\sin DAE$. Then $S_{\triangle ABG}=AB\cdot AG\cdot \sin BAG=AD\cdot AE\cdot \sin DAE=S_{\triangle ADE}$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu do you mean $AD \perp AB$? This helped a lot for my understanding, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us build congruent parallelograms by doubling the areas of the two triangles:

[image: math stackexchange problem equality of areas picture proof 4435676]

(The angles $\widehat{DAE}$ and $\widehat{GAB}$ add to $360^\circ-90^\circ-90^\circ=180^\circ$, so the two parallelograms have same angles and sides in $A$, respectively $G$, so they are congruent.)

The equality of areas (marked by brackets) is now clear:
$$
2[ADE] =[ADHE]=[AGIB]=2[AGB]\ .
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-$(1)$ In fig. $1$ two shaded triangles have equal areas (evident).

$(2)$ In fig $2$ green square is the smaller black square rotated of an angle $\phi$.

$(3)$ What you have to do is to prove that thick blue segments are equal so the shaded areas are equal too.

$(4)$ You do have two right triangles with equal angles $90^{\circ}-\phi$.[image]